# Simulink - From file block - Not defined time steps in .mat file (with examples)

Tags: matlab, time, time-series, simulink

I have file with a lot of data, for example here is a file with this data ->

```
time: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
data: 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
```

but in my file I have dropped the multiple data going in sequence like this ->

```
time: 1 2 3 8 9 10
data: 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

If I run this data the result is this ->

[image: http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/5047/v7nj.png]

My question is how to achieve result like in this picture shown with red arrows.
Simplier, how to repeat the value in not defined time steps (4,5,6,7 example above)

Answer (score 3):

you can achive this by not droping the final (7 in this example) like this:

```
time: 1 2 3 7 8 9 10
data: 1 0 1 1 0 1 0
```

this way simulink will interpolate ones there.

Comment: The issue is that my file is 500MB and more with thousands of value and it is impossible to edit it. I need to repeat the last signal if there is not defined the value in next step/second because in this file are defined only seconds where the values are changing.

Comment: Why do you need to (manually) edit the file?  Write some MATLAB code that adds the additional data points automatically based on the signal shape that you require, before passing the data to Simulink.

Answer (score 0):

Try: Double-click the "From File" block, then go to the option "Data extrapolation within time range:", and select "Zero order hold"